# How do I request user input until user enters valid input in ruby?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

This is a problem where they have asked me to add an additional if statement to re-prompt the user for input if they don't enter anything.

I have tried to use the while loop, but still can't solve the problem

```
print "please enter a sentence with a letter s"

while user_input = gets.chomp.downcase! 
  case user_input
  when user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub(/s/,"th")
    print "Daffy Duck says #{user_input}"
    break
  else
    print "please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  end
```

I expect "please enter a sentence with a letter s" to loop until the user enters the letter "s"

Comment: Why do you need a while statement for a case of two options? try with an `if-else`, also, why the gsub step?

Comment: There was a mistake in my code, it was meant to say user_input.gsub(/s/,"th"). So it replaces the s with th. Example if user enters enters "can i have some sugar" the out come would be "Daffy Duck says "can I have some thugar". Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that the user enters sentences until one contains an `"s"` or an `"S"`, at which time a certain action is taken and the program terminates.

Let's go through what you have.

```
print "Please enter a sentence with a letter s"
```

I think you want `puts`, which adds a newline character, rather than `print`, which does not.

```
while user_input = gets.chomp.downcase!
```

Suppose the user enters `"Cat"` (even though it's not a sentence), then presses the Enter key, then

```
str0 = gets
  #=> "Cat\n"
str1 = str0.chomp
  #=> "Cat"
user_input = str1.downcase!
  #=> "cat"
str1
  #=> "cat"
user_input
  #=> "cat"
```

so we have

```
while "cat"
```

As `"cat"` is neither `false` nor `nil` (the only logical `false` objects), this is the same as

```
while true
```

so execution moves to the first statement within the `while` loop. Suppose instead the user entered `"cat"` and pressed the Enter key. Then

```
str0 = gets
  #=> "cat\n"
str1 = str0.chomp
  #=> "cat"
user_input = str1.downcase!
  #=> nil
str1
  #=> "cat"
user_input
  #=> nil
```

so the program would not enter the `while` loop! How, you ask, can `"cat".downcase` return `nil`? Look at the doc for [String#downcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-downcase-21). It shows that `nil` is returned if there were no characters to downcase. Ruby has many methods that do the same: if the receiver is not altered `nil` is returned. (Don't get sidetracked with "why" at this point of your education.) For the present you are advised to avoid using *bang* methods (ending with an `"!"`).

Similarly, if the user didn't enter anything and pressed enter,

```
str1 = "\n".chomp
  #=> "" (an empty string)
user_input = str1.downcase
  #=> nil
```

`"".downcase!` returns `nil` for the same reason that `"cat".downcase!` does.

I think what you what here is the following.

```
user_input = gets.chomp
while !user_input.match?(/s/i)
```

`/s/i` is a regular expression used to determine if the string contains an `"s"` or an `"S"`. `i` in `/i` is a *case-indifference* modifier. (One could instead write `while user_input !~ /s/i`.)

The first statement within the `while` loop is

```
  case user_input
```

When `case` has an argument (here `user_input`) the `when` statements contain arguments that are possible values of the `case` argument, for example

```
  case user_input
  when "call me silly!"
    puts "You are silly"
  when...
```

You are not doing that here, so you want `case` on a line by itself:

```
case
when user_input == ...
  ...
end
```

Here, however, there is no need for a case statement or "if/elsif/else/end" construct within the loop because we have already determined that `user_input` does not contain an "s". All we need in the loop is this:

```
while !user_input.match?(/s/i)
  puts "Please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  user_input = gets.chomp
end
```

After the loop is terminated `user_input` is a string that contains an "s". We therefore need only perform the following.

```
puts "Daffy Duck says #{user_input}"
  #=> "Quack, quack, quackity-quack, sir"
```

Note that your statement

```
user_input.gsub(/s/, "s")
```

substitutes each "s" with an "s". :-) Nor is there a need for the `break` keyword.

Putting all this together, you could write:

```
puts "Please enter a sentence with a letter s"
user_input = gets.chomp
while !user_input.match?(/s/i)
  puts "Please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  user_input = gets.chomp
end
puts "Daffy Duck says #{user_input}"
```

You thought I was finished. Not so fast!

Firstly, many Ruby coders try to avoid negations such as `while !user_input.match?(/s/i)` (though it is purely a matter of taste). You could instead write that line

```
until user_input.match?(/s/i)
```

A more significant problem is the replication of code. You can improve upon that by using [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) and the keyword `break` instead of `while` or `until`.

```
loop do
  puts "Please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  user_input = gets.chomp
  if user_input.match?(/s/i)
    puts "Daffy Duck says #{user_input}"
    break
  end
end
```

If, however, we wrote

```
loop do
  puts "Please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  user_input = gets.chomp
  break if user_input.match?(/s/i)
end
puts "Daffy Duck says #{user_input}"
```

The last line would raise the exception

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `user_input' for main:Object)
```

because the variable `user_input` is only defined within the loop.

I generally use `loop` and `break` in preference to `while` or `until`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Very well explained, informative and polite.

Answer (score 1):

Is your problem a program not working?

What do you want to do the following?

```
please enter a sentence with a letter s: a
please enter a sentence with a letter s: s
Daffy Duck says: s
```

in this case,

```
print "please enter a sentence with a letter s: "

while user_input = gets
  user_input.chomp.downcase!
  if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub(/s/,"s")
    print "Daffy Duck says: #{user_input}"
    return
  else
    print "please enter a sentence with a letter s: "
  end
end
```

Comment: There was a mistake in my code, it was meant to say user_input.gsub(/s/,"th"). So it replaces the s with th. example if user enters enters "can i have some sugar" the out come would be "Daffy Duck says "can I have some thugar". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The i after /s/ is case-insensitive search.
If the string has an s and we remove it, the
original will not match

```
puts "please enter a sentence with a letter s"
while user_input = gets
  user_input = user_input.chomp
  if user_input != user_input.gsub(/s/i,"")
    puts "Daffy Duck says: #{user_input}"
    break
  else
    puts "please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  end
end
```

The match location will be a zero-based integer index if found
or nil if no match

```
puts "please enter another sentence with a letter s"
while user_input = gets
  user_input = user_input.chomp
  match_location =  user_input =~ /s/i
  if match_location.nil?
    puts "please enter a sentence with a letter s"
  else
    puts "Daffy Duck says: #{user_input}"
    break
  end
end
```